# Is it better to run one query returning a large quantity of rows or several smaller queries?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with 800M+ rows.
I have some process that need to loop over 500k+ rows from this table.

The query is a basic SELECT, without join nor aggregate function. The query is approximately:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = 1 AND time BETWEEN 123 AND 456;
```

With a composite index `(category, time)`.

Is is better to run one query returning all the required data, or to fetch rows in batch using several queries ?

Comment: FWIW, don't use `SELECT *`, instead explicitly list out only the columns that you need.

Comment: What will you do with the program do with all the rows?  Maybe we can fold more actions into the query.  (In other words, we need more information in order to give you the "right" answer.)

Answer (score 1):

So long as the consumer processes the rows as a stream rather than naively copies the entire result set into some kind of list or array of objects first, it will almost certainly be better to do just one query.

Answer (score 0):

Using just one query is better.

If you split it into "small query", you have to use the queries like ' limit N,M',

this query will visit all the M+N rows, it means you the rows will be visited multiple times.
Using one query can make sure the rows are visited once.

PS, when you use one big query, you should take into accout that, a long query may lead to a "long time transaction", which will make the undo log file bigger  if there are  heavy update in the server.